# Get rid of .active class with md-button and bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-material

**NOTE:** *This issue is more about **css** but as it creates problem with **angular2-material**, I'm adding **angular2** and **angular2-material** tags as well. Its kind of easy thing but I can't figure it out*

Without **`md-button`** in **`a tag`**, When I select an appropriate route, it selects and activates the current route correctly. Everything works as expected.

But after adding **`md-button`** to **`a tag`**, it works fine but it adds **blue border** to the selected **`a tag`**.

I tried to figure it out but unable to identify what adds **`blue border`**. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**How to reproduce**: after adding **`bootstrap`** to **`index.html`** page, issue can be produced with existing setup.If I remove bootstap, everything works fine but I want bootstrap so can't remove it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Iy4inAUDeBFb6xPMg9gC?p=preview

Comment: Your plunkr has a whole lot of files. Please come up with a minimal example. And try to post one that reproduces the problem: I can't see any blue border anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried? `nav a:focus { outline: 0; }` https://plnkr.co/edit/GbYaQMGcz46Xut9MLW1z?p=preview http://take.ms/jRzBB

Comment: Thanks @yurzui.  It resolved it.

Comment: Plunker does not work.